# Separate HTML and code behind on different servers

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, web

I'm building a web forms app and was wondering for deployment, if I could split out the "web" (HTML/aspx) layer and the "app" (C#/aspx.cs) layer onto different servers?

I've made sure all DB calls are made via the code behind (aspx.cs) and the web is strictly HTML (as I want users to hit web, which will hit app which will hit DB).

Is it possible? If so how does it get done, I mean I assume I would deploy the C# aspx.cs to a different IIS server but how do I point the web server/files to that?

Thanks.

Comment: ?! If pages are _"strictly HTML"_ then you don't have any aspx.cs files for them...if they're not then no, you can't split anything (btw .cs are there only during development, not in production) across servers (unless you're talking about load balancing, in that case they're duplicated in many servers and requests are redirected properly). Of course you can store plain HTML pages in another server and you can link to them (or download them into your aspx page...but I wonder why).

Comment: You don't usually deploy the .cs files at all, you deploy only the compiled DLL.

Comment: as i understood from your question, you want to build a thin client with middle tier that will deal with your database on different server, if so, you can build a web service on one server and your web application will use the web service to retrieve the data from database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if I could split out the "web" (HTML/aspx) layer and the "app" (C#/aspx.cs) layer onto different servers?

Yes, but not in the way you're thinking.

What you're describing is building a multi-tier system, where different logical layers (application logic and business logic) are on separate physical machines.  To do that, first you need to separate your application logic from your business logic.

This does *not* mean putting the `.aspx` files in one place and the code-behind (the `.dll`s in this case) in another.  *Both* the application layer *and* the business logic layer have code.

What this does mean is creating two applications.  One is your front-end web application, which includes all of the user interface and any code used to drive that interface.  The other is a service application (probably a web service, at least for starters) which *technically* has its own interface, that interface is just service operations and not an HTML-based UI.

The front-end application would basically handle user requests, interact with the business application (ideally one back-end request per front-end request, if the use cases are set up correctly), and respond back to the user with the responses.  The benefits of this approach include:

- Other applications can share the same back-end business logic service.
- Database access can be secured behind the back-end service, which can have stricter host security than the web server(s).
- The UI and the back-end services can scale separately.
- The UI can be managed separately and easily changed/replaced without affecting business logic.

Comment: Yes - you practically read my mind :). That makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. One server runs IIS (or other web server) and serves up HTML/CSS/JS/Image files and the other server, running a set of web services (using WCF for example) can contain a lot of your back-end code written in C# (or your language of choice).

May or may not be the best way to do it,and will vary depending on the solution you are providing, but technologically it would work fine.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, this answers my question - can't upvote you though as I need more rep.